# Cloudflare CDN: problem with compressed asset on original server

Tags: cloudflare

I use Cloudflare CDN for assets, my origin server is Azure Storage Blob.

All azure blobs are gzipped and have the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age = 1800
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Official Cloudflare documentation at
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168086-Does-Cloudflare-compress-resources-
declares:

> Cloudflare's reverse proxy is also able to convert between compressed
> formats and uncompressed formats, meaning that it can ** pull content
> from a customer's origin server via gzip and serve it to clients
> uncompressed ** (or vice versa). This is done independently of
> caching.

but when Cloudflare caches my assets, they remain gzipped. My web application use Range Request so I need uncompressed assets in cache.

### Question

- Is it possible to have compressed asset at original server and uncompressed asset at Cloudflare CDN cache?
- What headers x Cloudflare settings are needed?